# How to align an absolute DIV of unknown height outside a "relative" parent by CSS?

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

Consider a simple [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mqy4z/) with html

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.parent{
    position:relative;
    background:red;
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
}
.child{
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    left:30px;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    background:blue;
}
```

to place a DIV with absolute position just beneath its parent (with relative position). 
[image]

In this example, I equaled the absolute's top to the parent relative's height.

How to align the absolute DIV just under the parent when **the height is unknown** (both parent and child)?

Comment: The answer by Simon below will fix your problem, I have to question why this is needed in the first place though?  Seems to me like you should just have a container with two childs in it, one  child is the red box the other is the blue box?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Didn't think [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mqy4z/1/) would work myself, but it seems to:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.parent{
    position:relative;
    background:red;
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
}
.child{
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:30px;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    background:blue;
}
```

Comment: Well on second thought it's totally obvious, center alignment with `left: 50%` and negative margin works as well, so why should this not? :)

Comment: Your idea works well, I didn't think that `top:100%` can play this trick :)

Answer (score 3):

Check this..

```
HTML:
-------

<div class="parent">
</div> 
<div class="child">
</div>

CSS:
-----
.parent{
    position:relative;
    background:red;
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
}
.child{
    position:absolute;
    top:auto;
    left:30px;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    background:blue;
}
```

[(Example)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sriganesh/mqy4z/6/)

Comment: Hm if I adjust my fiddle to this, it doesn't seem to work correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/mqy4z/5/

Comment: @simon you miss the html to separate both div.

Comment: I guess because it needs to adjust the HTML while my solution is CSS only

Comment: yeah... might be. Ok no worries..  :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use negative value for bottom, eg. `bottom: -100px`

EDIT: here is better solution: http://jsfiddle.net/mqy4z/3/ - set child's position to `top:100%`

Comment: what if the height of absolute DIV is unknown too?

Comment: Unknown height is the key here. You can't set a pixel dimension if you don't know the height.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing both div's in your HTML file under eachother:

```
<div class="parent">
</div>

<div class="child">
</div>
```